# Find Mysql's Master Binary Log Position in Slave's Binary Log

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql master/slave replication setup and I like to know the binary position in the slave where it executed the query from the master. I have log_slave_updates enabled on slave. So, is this is the right process?

On the master, I do show master status and it says mysql-bin.000001, 45408621 (assume this is the position that I want to know its equivalent in the slave's binary log).

Then I do a mysqlbinlog on the master's mysql-bin.000001, and I look for that position 45408621 which will be this

```
   # at 45408621
   #190620 17:39:21 server id 118  end_log_pos 45408704 CRC32 0x481aab34
   # Position  Timestamp   Type   Master ID        Size      Master Pos    Flags
   #  2b4e16d 39 27 0c 5d   02   73 00 00 00   53 00 00 00   c0 e1 b4 02   08 00
   #  2b4e180 9b 87 1b 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 27 00 00 00 00 |................|
   #  2b4e190 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 06 03 73 74 64 |.............std|
   #  2b4e1a0 03 02 00 01 00 04 21 00  21 00 21 00 05 06 53 59 |..............SY|
   #  2b4e1b0 53 54 45 4d 65 62 00 42  45 47 49 4e 34 ab 1a 48 |STEMeb.BEGIN4..H|
   #       Query   thread_id=1804187       exec_time=0     error_code=0
   SET TIMESTAMP=1561077561/*!*/;
   BEGIN
```

Then on the slave, I ran mysqlbinlog on its last binary log (eg. mysql-slave-bin.000001) and grep for the "17:39:21" and the thread id of 1804187, and I get this

```
   # at 12506
   #190620 17:39:21 server id 118  end_log_pos 12574 CRC32 0x0802ae3f
   # Position  Timestamp   Type   Master ID        Size      Master Pos    Flags
   #     30da 39 27 0c 5d   02   73 00 00 00   44 00 00 00   1e 31 00 00   08 00
   #     30ed 9b 87 1b 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 |................|
   #     30fd 00 00 01 00 00 08 00 00  00 00 00 03 02 00 01 00 |................|
   #     310d 04 21 00 21 00 21 00 00  42 45 47 49 4e 3f ae 02 |........BEGIN...|
   #     311d 08                                               |.|
   #   Query   thread_id=1804187   exec_time=0 error_code=0
   SET TIMESTAMP=1561077561/*!*/;
   BEGIN
```

Can I conclude that the master's position of (mysql-bin.000001, 45408621) is equal to the slave's position (mysql-slave-bin.000001, 12506) in the slav
e's binary log?

And if this is the correct process, is there a simpler way of doing this? Maybe someone has written some script already for this?

Comment: Are you running with GTIDs?

Comment: No, I am not running with GTIDs.

Comment: Two queries can come from the same thread_id at the same second.

Comment: Hmm... that's why I also showed the SQL that it executed... in this case, BEGIN... would that be enough?

Comment: The binlog is not written until the `COMMIT`.  Note:  This implies that queries can be written to the binlog not in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks... so it looks like this method is not reliable. Do you know of a method to get this information?

Comment: But...  The Master's binlog is copied _in order_ to the slaves 'relay log'.  The difference in position comes from binlog/replicate-do/ignore clauses and cycling of log files after 1GB (or whatever your limit is).

Comment: I think all I have said so far is "your grep is not sufficient".  If the grep comes back with 2 lines, then you need to figure out which one.

Comment: GTIDs were invented to solve the problem you are chasing.  (Hence, my initial question.)

Comment: Oh...  With multi-source replication, it gets messier.  I assume you are not doing that?

Comment: Ah, then if there are 2 thread_ids at the same time... probably I will just repeat the process. Get a new master position, and find the position in the slave's binary log grepping for the time and thread_id... not optimal but is this good enough?

Comment: What action will you take when you find the position??  Replaying a binlog is dangerous -- replication could hang do to an error, or a value could be screwed up due to rerunning `UPDATE ... SET x = x + 1`.

Comment: We use row-based replication so this specific case will not be a problem. This is a hypothetical question.